# ChIP-sequence data analysis

Tags: report, data-analysis

I have a ChIP-seq report from a company. I would like to find peak-associated genes regulated in ChIP-seq data. I have many files like fastqr; mapping; peak calling; peak annotation; diff; findMotifs... and the backup. But I do not know how to find... I have checked the peak calling and peak annotation. Thank you in advance for your help, I've been struggling for a few months.